# How to update Materializecss Autocomplete through Server side?

Tags: c#, autocomplete, materialize, master-pages

I have WebForms Page that uses a Master Page. I am trying to accomplish [Materializecss Autocomplete](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) functionality on an entry that contains around 1000+ values. Dropdown won't be feasible because I have three of those entries on single page. It works on static content.
Now I want to load the `data` from an async postback on textchange. I tried google but found nothing matching exactly what I want.

This code is at the end of the WebForms Page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var acMElems = document.querySelectorAll('input.autocomplete');
    var acMInstances = M.Autocomplete.init(acMElems);
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: { 
            "Apple": null,
            "Microsoft": null,
            "Google": null
            },
        limit: 20,
        minLength: 1
    });
});
</script>
```

At the end of Master Page:

CS Server Side code that runs on TextChange event:
 
    `strScript = @"acMInstances.updateData({
        "val1": null,
        "val2": null,
        "gal1": null
    });";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((sender as Control), GetType(), DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString(), strScript, true);`

The error that I am getting in Firefox console:

> autocomplete() is not defined

Comment: I also tried to implement autocomplete from server side. But finally I had to use jquey-UI's  autocomplete with materializecss chips. You may need to work more on java-script, better to switch to any other JS plugin or library that you used to.

Comment: How does that work in .NET (mind the async postback requirement) ? please give a link to sample. Thanks

Comment: I tried what you said @Codesigner, but now I have issue of UrlRewrite. I am using WebService, I can access the service through address bar, but the code is not touched when using through another page.
>ReferenceError: $ is not defined